# xmllint xsd:selector xpath behaviour different from --xpath or --shell

Tags: xpath, xsd, libxml2, xmllint

The command:
**xmllint myfile.xml --xpath 'MapField2Data[@country="FR"]/*[@active!="false" or not(@active) ]'**
**works as expected** for my xml structure

**But** trying to use it in an xsd, it fails to compile:

**xmllint** --loaddtd --noout --noent --xinclude **--schema** xsd/pnsConf.xsd pnsConf.xml
 
xsd/pnsConf.xsd:75: element selector: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}selector', attribute 'xpath': The **XPath expression 'MapField2Data[@country="FR"]/*[@active!="false" or not(@active) ]' could not be compiled**.

My xsd has a proper

```
<xsd:selector xpath='MapField2Data[@country="FR"]/*[@active!="false" or not(@active) ]'/>
```

Where a simpler xpath like 'MapField2Data/*' works fine in both situations.
This looks like a bug or a missing feature in xmllint or libxml2.
**Should I file a bug on the gnome bugzilla for xmllint?**

Maybe there is **another solution to my problem** in the mean time?

I want "active" tags to be unique and ignore non-active tags in a structure such as this one:

```
<MapField2Data country='FR' >
    <raw id='NoUnReadMails' active='true'>
            <depend ref='_EndMailNotif'/>
            <depend ref='_EndMailSub' />
    </raw>
    <raw id='NoUnReadMails' active='false'>
            <depend ref='_EndMailNotif'/>
            <depend ref='_EndMailSub' />
    </raw>
    <raw id='NoEMails' >
            <depend ref='_EndMailNotif'/>
            <depend ref='_EndMailSub' />
    </raw>
...
```

Regards,
Emmanuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. `xsd:selector` only allows a [restricted set of XPath operations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-identity-constraint). Your expression uses predicates which are not allowed. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746957/how-can-i-use-attribute-constraint-on-xsdselector-element-in-xsdkey-or-xsduni).